# Download .CSV file sent by user [Discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a discord bot which takes data from .CSV files, which are regularly updated. To do this I would like my bot to download the .CSV file when it is sent into a specific text channel. I found the .attachments object in discord.py: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments

How do I download one of these .CSV attachments into my project though (I am using Pycharm)

Is this even Possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Looking through documentaion:
using .save() https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.save

i managed to do this.

If anyone is looking for how they could do this themselves:

```
if str(message.attachments) == "[]": # Checks if there is an attachment on the message
    return
else: # If there is it gets the filename from message.attachments
    split_v1 = str(message.attachments).split("filename='")[1]
    filename = str(split_v1).split("' ")[0]
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): # Checks if it is a .csv file
        await message.attachments[0].save(fp="CsvFiles/{}".format(filename)) # saves the file
```

fp in .save() is what the new file should be called. this works with really any file type, if you want to download only .txt files change the second if statement to .txt instead of .csv If you want the bot to download all files, so images, text files, csv file, python files etc. Just get rid of that if statement.

Hope this helps anyone else who stumbles across the same problem as me

Comment: This is a good answer, but just keep in mind that checking if `filename` ends with .csv does not ensure that the file is a valid CSV file. If you want true validation you need to come up with a different method to check.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are converting `message.attachments` to a str to check if it is an empty list? You can just do `if message.attachments == []` or `if len(message.attachments) < 1`.

Comment: @Cloud there isnt really a reason for converting it to str i mean it works the same so. To check if it is a valid csv file couldnt i just do try and except statement though? like try: open() and expect error: ?

Comment: That should work. Also, it's slower if you convert it to a str (not by a meaningful amount, but still).

Comment: Something that I didn't notice yesterday is the way you were getting the filename. You are doing some weird string conversion with split at the moment. You can just do `message.attachments[0].filename` to get it.

Comment: h i tried message.attachments.filename to get it and it didnt work i didint realize i could do that

Comment: also i changed it to if message.attachments: to simplify

Comment: So I will probably improve the code and update it